# What is the meaning of exportSchema = false or true in Room Database?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have noticed exportSchema keyword while creating Room Database in Database class

```
   @Database(entities = [SleepNight::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyDB : RoomDatabase() {
}
```

i am not getting why exportSchema needs to be false or true ? How does it effects on DB?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Database#exportSchema()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As given in below link, exportSchema is use to export database schema to the given folder when the variable-> room.schemaLocation="your schema location path" argument is set. Defaults to true.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Database#exportSchema()